# Removing a color in image - CSS, HTML, JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm wondering how to remove a color in an image on a webpage. I want some kind of result like explained here...

An image with three segments: blue, purple, and red. I want to filter out all the blue so it ends up with the segments: black, red, and red.

blue purple red -> black red red

I know this would be done in CSS or JavaScript in some way but I do not know how I would do it. I've been messing with CSS `filter`s and even putting a `div` on top of it that is a certain color, but nothing will get rid of the blue.

Does anyone know how to do this / is it possible?

Comment: I would use photoshop, generate different versions of the image, then just change which image shows with JavaScript / CSS

Comment: What sort of speed do you need?  And is the image coming from your local box or are you pulling images from remote servers?  You can get real-time from shaders, or slow-time using canvases (see Rycochet's answer), but it's a security exception to look at arbitrary images from the internet without server compliance.

Comment: Speed is no real issue here. As long as it doesn't take a worrying amount of time, it'll be good. The user uploads the image and then the color gets filtered. Note that PHP is not available to me for this. Using an external program is not an option either.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS filters however, i don't think there is a filter for a specific colour and browser compatibility is limited.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Alternatively you could use an SVG image which allows you to modify certain parts of an image using CSS however i think SVG files can get pretty big for large images...
I think you can use adobe illustrator to save files as SVG.
http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_myfirst

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more complicated, but far more compatible - load the image into a canvas, and then use getImageData within it, filter out whichever colours you don't want, then paste it back again.

It's not a quick (framerate) process - getImageData is a really slow function so an HD screen won't hit 60fps on anything except the most powerful machine. Saying that, if you're not trying to animate it then it's perfect ;-)

Comment: I'm going to look into this one... this may be it. Speed, as I stated in a comment above, is no issue here.

Comment: I used this method however I get an error in my console: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

Comment: Ugh, cross-origin security can be a complete pain. If you need it for all browsers then this is a fail, otherwise you can get it working on some, or you're going to have to make sure that the images are on the same source domain :-/

Comment: And just realised - the user is uploading the image, you could conceivably take their source image and manipulate that before uploading (and send 2 versions etc) - which should bypass the security issue.

Comment: The user technically isn't uploading the image - they give a link on the web which is then used for the result. Is there a way to maybe put a littice of colored `<div>`s over the top of it to try and make some kind of a color-cancelling effect? It did work with putting cyan over an image, or at least seemed to, but red doesn't work like that at all.

Comment: Not sure then - that cross-origin thing just gets in the way here. You could try things like getting it as a toDataUrl then pasting again, but I've got a feeling it'll hit the same limitation. Alternatively use a proxy that allows it through, or (if it was an extension etc) make sure you get the relevant permission to bypass that...

Comment: I tried `toDataUrl` but it did hit the same issue. I am also limited by the editor I'm writing this on. Only normal HTML, CSS, and JS are available to me. I also tried putting a tag on the element itself but it again hit the security issue.